# Select parent of XCUIElement

Tags: xcuitest

How can I select the parent element of an `XCUIElement` in XCUITest? According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement), the class has `children()` and `descendants()` but nothing to select parents or siblings. It seems to me I must be missing something - how can Apple have an element tree without navigation in both directions???

I know there is a method `containing()` on `XCUIElementQuery` but that is not the same. I also know that an `accessibilityIdentifier` might help but I am thinking of writing a generic method for testing any view with a given Navbar label. Passing in all the identifiers of all the elements I would like to access does not seem like a good option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct named method to access parent elements similar to `children()` and `descendants()` provided by Apple but you were actually on the right track with `containing()`. There are two ways I usually approach it when I need to locate a parent element based on children/descendants:

1. Using `containing(_:identifier:)`
   `let parentElement = app.otherElements.containing(.textField, identifier: "test").firstMatch`
   or
   `let parentElement = app.otherElements.containing(.textField, identifier: "test").element(boundBy: 0)`
2. Using `containing(_ predicate: NSPredicate)`
   `let parentElement = app.otherElements.containing(NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS[c] 'test'").firstMatch`
   or
   `let parentElement = app.otherElements.containing(NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS[c] 'test'").element(boundBy: 0)`

These are just examples with random data/element types because you didn't mention exactly what you want to achieve but you can go from there.

Update:
As usual the Apple documentation doesn't do a good service. They say 'descendants' but what they actually mean is both direct descendants(children) and non-direct descendants(descendants). Unfortunately there is no guarantee and there is no generic solution. It should be based on your current needs and the application implementation. More examples that could be useful:

1. If you don't want the first element from the query you are better off using `element(boundBy: index)`. So if you know that XCUIElementQuery will give you 5 elements and you know you need the 3rd one:
   `let parentElement = app.otherElements.containing(.textField, identifier: "test").element(boundBy: 2)`
2. Fine graining of your element locators. Lets say you have 3 views with identifier "SomeView", these 3 views each contain 2 other subviews and the subviews have a button with identifier "SomeButton".

```
let parentViews = app.otherElements.matching(identifier: "SomeView")
let subView = parentViews.element(boundBy: 2).otherElements.containing(.button, identifier: "SomeButton").element(boundBy: 1)
```

This will give you the second subview containing a button with identifier "SomeButton" from the third parent view with identifier "SomeView". Using such an approach you can fine tune until you get exactly what you need and not all parents, grandparents, great-grandparents etc.

I wish Apple provided a bit more flexibility for the locators with XCTest like Xpath does for Appium but even these tools can be sufficient most of the time.

Comment: Thanks. How do I know that `firstMatch` is the one I want? `containing()` looks for elements that have the given element as a descendant, not those that have it as a child. So, I would find parents, grandparents, great-grandparents... I am genuinely looking for a generic answer, that's why I did not specify a specific scenario.

Comment: I've updated the answer, I hope it makes it more clear and helpful

Comment: Thanks. It looks like a negative answer may get to be the accepted one. This sucks. I am relatively new to XCUITest and have spent most of my time trying to figure out how to select things. Most ways of inspecting the element tree are broken one way or another, too. #notimpressedwithapple

Comment: I'm really sorry to be the one to disappoint you, mate, but at least you can rest knowing that we all struggle with this. Fine graining the locators bit by bit and as many ```accessibilityIdentifiers``` are your best bets :)